# Pivot table summation of "values" with respect to "columns"

Tags: pandas, pivot-table

I'm pretty new to pandas and currently unsure whether it is possible to sum values with respect to columns instead of a lump sum using margin=True. Currently, I have built this table using Microsoft Excel's pivot table function as a reference.

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
    'company_country': ['C1', 'C1', 'C2', 'C2',  'C3',  'C4',  'C4'],
    'Company': ['Company1', 'Company2', 'Company3', 'Company4', 'Company5', 'Company6', 'Company7'],
    'Sales': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50 , 60, 70],
    'Gross Margin': [40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100],
    'invoice_date': ['Week1', 'Week1', 'Week2', 'Week2', 'Week3', 'Week4', 'Week4'],
    'Account_code': ['3P', 'Inter-company', '3P', 'Inter-company', 'Inter-company', '3P', 'Inter-company']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data,
                  columns=['company_country',
                           'Company',
                           'Sales',
                           'Gross Margin',
                           'invoice_date',
                           'Account_code'
                           ]
                  )
data_summarised = pd.pivot_table(df, index=["company_country", "Company"],
                                 values=["Sales", "Gross Margin"],
                                 columns=["invoice_date", "Account_code"],
                                 aggfunc=[np.sum],
                                 fill_value=0,
                                 margins=True)
data_summarised.columns = data_summarised.columns.droplevel(0)
data_summarised.columns = data_summarised.columns.swaplevel(0, 1)
data_summarised.columns = data_summarised.columns.swaplevel(1, 2)

print(data_summarised)
```

The output is:

```
invoice_date                    Week1                ...         Week4   All
Account_code                       3P Inter-company  ... Inter-company      
                         Gross Margin  Gross Margin  ...         Sales Sales
company_country Company                              ...                    
C1              Company1           40             0  ...             0    10
                Company2            0            50  ...             0    20
C2              Company3            0             0  ...             0    30
                Company4            0             0  ...             0    40
C3              Company5            0             0  ...             0    50
C4              Company6            0             0  ...             0    60
                Company7            0             0  ...            70    70
All                                40            50  ...            70   280

[8 rows x 16 columns]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

The question:
Is it possible to have columns added to this table with the column name "Sum of 3P Sales", "Sum of inter-company Sales", "Sum of 3P Gross Margin" and "Sum of inter-company Gross Margin" instead of just total sales and gross margin?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sum values per second and third levels of MultiIndex, add third level for same number of levels like `data_summarised`:

```
df = data_summarised.sum(level=[1,2], axis=1).drop('', axis=1, level=0)

df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('Sum', *x) for x in df.columns])
print (df)
                                  Sum                                  
                                   3P Inter-company    3P Inter-company
                         Gross Margin  Gross Margin Sales         Sales
company_country Company                                                
C1              Company1           40             0    10             0
                Company2            0            50     0            20
C2              Company3           60             0    30             0
                Company4            0            70     0            40
C3              Company5            0            80     0            50
C4              Company6           90             0    60             0
                Company7            0           100     0            70
All                               190           300   100           180
```

And then add to original:

```
data_summarised = df.join(data_summarised).sort_index(axis=1)
```